# 10 year re-entry ban

Tags: visas, uk, visa-bans

I got a 10 year re-entry ban for a visitor visa. Can I apply for student dependent visa or not?

The notice said "This application for entry clearance has been refused under paragraph320 (7a) and 320(7b), subject to the requirement set out in paragraph 320(7c)."

Comment: Your ban was for deception. I do not think you can apply after a ban under 320(7a)/(b) unless your sponsor has settled status https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse But you should ask on Expatriates

Comment: Even if the ban doesn't apply, your credibility is nil. You'll have an uphill task persuading the ECO that your application can be believed.